# Python mechanize wait and click

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

Using mechanize, how can I wait for some time after page load (some websites have a timer before links appear, like in download pages), and after the links have been loaded, click on a specific link?
Since it's an anchor tag and not a submit button, will browser.submit() work(I got errors while doing that)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mechanize does not offer javascript functionality, so you will not see dynamic content (like a timer that turns into a link).

As far as clicking on a link, you have to find the element, and then you can call click_link on it. See the `Finding Links` section of [this site](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet).

If you are looking for something to handle such sites, a good option is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). It uses nodejs, but runs on the webkit engine, allowing you parse dynamic content. If you have your heart set on python, using [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org) to programatically drive a real browser may be your best bet.

Comment: +1 for the important point about not having dynamic nature. Hence, there is no need to wait for page to load, it is not `selenium`.

Comment: What about using time.sleep() for that many seconds and then refreshing the page using mechanize? Does mechanize have such an option, and will this technique reset the timer? Is there an alternative solution other than mechanize and selenium?

Comment: You can sleep the python process, but it doesn't matter as the timeout in the webpage uses javascript to count and then switch out the link.

Comment: Another possible option is to identify the relevant script tag and pull the anchor tag out of it. (Presuming that is is pre-calculated or there is an identifiable structure you can use to generate the link yourself)

Answer (score 0):

If it's an anchor tag, then just GET/POST whatever it is.

The timer between links appearing is generally done in javascript - some sites you are attempting to scrape may not be usable without javascript, or requires a token generated in javascript with clientside math.

Depending on the site, you can either extract the wait time in msec/sec and time.sleep() for that long, or you'll have to use something that can execute javascript